# UIViewController not calling dealloc or calling it twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

I have some problem with my singleton and UIViewController there;

Singleton.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *viewController;
```

Singleton.m

```
...

@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (void)load {
   self.viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle: nil] autorelease];
}

- (void)unload {
   [_viewController release];
}
```

This `viewController` using by different part of the application via `pushViewController:animated:`. But sometimes I need to release `viewController` by calling method `- (void)unload` of Singleton class! If `pushViewController:animated:` never call for `viewController` everything is well and dealloc is calling, but if pushViewController(and viewController perform viewDidLoad), dealloc isn't work. If I do something like `self.viewController = nil;` dealloc calling twice... What I'm doing wrong???

Comment: structure of all viewController
UITabBarController - rootViewController
--UINavigationController
----UIViewController
------`viewController` - `pushViewController:animated:`
I'm trying to release rootViewController - all views are released only `viewController` has problems. Before releasing rootViewController I'm calling - (void)unload

Answer (score 1):

Your unload function should only consist of:

```
- (void)unload {
   self.viewController = nil;
}
```

When you set a retained property to nil, it releases the instance variable AND nils it. You are simply leaving a dangling pointer on your property here.

Comment: It's not worked. Only if I'm using [_viewController release]; and self.viewController = nil; dealloc is calling, BUT twice. Maybe this helps: _viewController has MPMoviePlayerController which is playing...

Comment: @RostK. You have an extra retain then, because that code will release it twice.  Use instruments to track to retains and releases of this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it to `nil` after releasing it:

```
[_viewController release];
_viewController = nil;
```

Otherwise the next person who comes along will try to do stuff with an invalid pointer.